# gethostbyname() and getaddrinfo() blocks forever (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am porting my code from Windows to Linux and I got stuck on a problem: any call to gethostbyname() or getaddrinfo() blocks forever.

```
struct hostent* hEnt;
hEnt = gethostbyname( "www.google.com" );
```

or

```
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo* ai;
int                 retVal;

memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( struct addrinfo ) );
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
hints.ai_addr = NULL;
hints.ai_next = NULL;

retVal = getaddrinfo( "www.google.com", NULL, &hints, &ai );
```

ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) works just fine. Adding [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) to /etc/hosts does not help much, so this is not a network issue.

I am testing on Debian 11 under Hyper-V.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quoth the manpage: "The gethostbyname*(), gethostbyaddr*(), herror(), and hstrerror() functions are obsolete.  Applications should use getaddrinfo(3), getnameinfo(3), and gai_strerror(3) instead."

Comment: Yes, getaddrinfo() was what I tried first. No luck as well.

Comment: Well, no matter what the result, you shouldn't use an obsolete API, so maybe show your `getaddrinfo()` attempt?

Comment: Both snippets of code you've provided, as shown, should have worked. Also, `ping` calls `getaddrinfo` itself, so something _like_ them _does_ work.  The problem must be in some other part of the program. Please provide a _complete program_ that blocks forever.